# Show that if $f_0 \simeq f_1 \text{ rel } A$ and $g_0 \simeq g_1 \text{ rel }B$, then $g_0 \circ f_0 \simeq g_1 \circ f_1 \text{ rel } A$.

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$ and suppose that $f_0,f_1 : X \to Y$ with $f_0\mid_A = f_1\mid_A$ and $f_i(A) \subset B$ for $i=0,1.$ Assume also that $g_0,g_1:Y \to Z$ are such that $g_0\mid_B =g_1\mid_B$. Show that if $f_0 \simeq f_1 \text{ rel } A$ and $g_0 \simeq g_1 \text{ rel }B$, then $g_0 \circ f_0 \simeq g_1 \circ f_1 \text{ rel } A$.

In order for $g_0 \circ f_0 \simeq g_1 \circ f_1 \text{ rel } A$ to be true I would need a homotopy $H:X \times I \to Z$ such that $H(x,0)=(g_0 \circ f_0)(x)$, $H(x,1)=(g_1 \circ f_1)(x)$ and $H(a,t)=(g_0 \circ f_0)(a)=(g_1 \circ f_1)(a)$ for all $a \in A$.

Now given the relative homotopies $F: f_0 \simeq f_1$ and $F':g_0 \simeq g_1$ I thought I could just compose these and get the result, but this isn't true.

I then considered $$H(x,t)=\begin{cases} g_0(F(x,t)), 0\le t \le 1/2 \\ g_1(F(x,t)), 1/2 \le t \le 1 \end{cases}$$

for which I have that $H(x,0)=g_0(f_0(x))$ and $H(x,1)=g_1(f_1(x))$, but I don't think that the last condition holds for this homotopy?

Answer (score 1):

The map $H$ that you defined is not continuous at $t = 1/2$ since
$$ \lim_{t \to 1/2^-} H(x,t) = g_0(F(x,1/2)) \\
\lim_{t \to 1/2^+} H(x,t) = g_1(F(x,1/2))$$
and $g_0$ coincides with $g_1$ only over $B \subset Y$, so that for $x \notin A$ the two values aren't necessarily the same.

Instead, you can define
$$ H(x,t) = G(F(x,t),t), $$
which is continuous as a composition of continuous maps and satisfies:

- $ H(x,0) = G(F(x,0),0) = G(f_0(x), 0) = g_0(f_0(x)) $
- $ H(x,1) = G(F(x,1),1) = G(f_1(x), 1) = g_1(f_1(x)) $
- $ \forall a \in A : H(a,t) = G(F(a,t),t) = G(f_0(a),t) = g_0(f_0(a)) $
- $ \forall a \in A : H(a,t) = G(F(a,t),t) = G(f_1(a),t) = g_1(f_1(a)) $

The last two lines show that the homotopy $H$ is relative to $A$.